# Python - why the print result is repeated and "write to a text" only has one line

Tags: python, web-scraping

Lovely people! I'm totally new with Python. I tried to scrape several URLs and encountered a problem with "print".

I tried to print and write the "shipment status".
I have two URLs, so ideally I get two results.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re 
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib 
 
# read urls of websites from text file 
list_open = open("c:/Users/***/Downloads/web list.txt") 
read_list = list_open.read() 
line_in_list = read_list.split("\n") 
 
for url in line_in_list: 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html') 
    # parse something special in the file 
    shipment = soup.find_all('span')
    Preparation=shipment[0] 
    Sent=shipment[1]
    InTransit=shipment[2]
    Delivered=shipment[3]
    for p in shipment: 
# extract information 
        print (url,';',"Preparation",Preparation.getText(),";","Sent",Sent.getText(),";","InTransit",InTransit.getText(),";","Delivered",Delivered.getText())
     
import sys
 
file_path = 'randomfile.txt'
sys.stdout = open(file_path, "w")
print(url,';',"Preparation",Preparation.getText(),";","Sent",Sent.getText(),";","InTransit",InTransit.getText(),";","Delivered",Delivered.getText())`
```

I have two problems here:

1. Problem one: I have only two URLs, and when I print the results, every "span" is repeated 4 times (as there are four "span"s).
   The result in the "output" is as below:

(I deleted the result example to protect privacy.)

2. Problem two: I tried to write the "print" to a text file, but only one line appeared in the file:

(I deleted the result example to protect privacy.)

I want to know what is wrong in the code. I want to print 2 url results only.

Your help is really appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point is caused by iterating over shipment - Just delete the for loop and correct indent of `print()`:

```
for url in line_in_list: 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html') 
    # parse something special in the file 
    shipment = soup.find_all('span')
    Preparation=shipment[0] 
    Sent=shipment[1]
    InTransit=shipment[2]
    Delivered=shipment[3]

    print (url,';',"Preparation",Preparation.getText(),";","Sent",Sent.getText(),";","InTransit",InTransit.getText(),";","Delivered",Delivered.getText())
```

Second issue is caused while you call the writing outside the loop and not in append mode - You will end up with this as your loop:

```
#open file in append mode
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as f:
    #start iterating your urls
    for url in line_in_list: 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html') 
        # parse something special in the file 
        shipment = soup.find_all('span')
        Preparation=shipment[0] 
        Sent=shipment[1]
        InTransit=shipment[2]
        Delivered=shipment[3]
        #create output text
        line = f'{url};Preparation{Preparation.getText()};Sent{Sent.getText()};InTransit{InTransit.getText()};Delivered{Delivered.getText()}'
        #print output text
        print (line)
        #append output text to file
        f.write(line+'\n')
```

And you can delete:

```
import sys
file_path = 'randomfile.txt'
sys.stdout = open(file_path, "w")
print(url,';',"Preparation",Preparation.getText(),";","Sent",Sent.getText(),";","InTransit",InTransit.getText(),";","Delivered",Delivered.getText())`
```

#### Example of a bit optimized code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib

# read urls of websites from text file
list_open = open("c:/Users/***/Downloads/web list.txt")
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split("\n")
file_path = "randomfile.txt"

with open('somefile.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for url in line_in_list:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html') 
        # parse something special in the file 
        shipment = list(soup.select_one('#progress').stripped_strings)
        line = f"{url},{';'.join([':'.join(x) for x in list(zip(shipment[::2], shipment[1::2]))])}"
        print (line)
        f.write(line+'\n')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! I tried the code and had "NameError: name 'html' is not defined". Something is wrong here?

Comment: @SliviaWu: Sorry my fault - Worked with your example data and almost edited my example to -> `soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html')`. Take a look and try again, thanks

Comment: Many thanks for your follow-up! I tried the updated code and got " soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html')
NameError: name 'url' is not defined". I have to bother you again to understand how to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your update - `for url in line_in_list:` missed, so there was no url to create the BeautifulSoup object  - Fixed that.

Comment: Many thanks! I retried it, and it worked! Thank you a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

### First question

You have two nested loops :

```py
for url in line_in_list:
    for p in shipment:
        print(...)
```

The print is nested in the second loop. If you have 4 shipments per url, that will lead to 4 prints per url.

Since you don't use `p` from `for p in shipment` you can completely get rid of the second loop and move the print one indentation level left, like this :

```py
for url in line_in_list: 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html') 
    # parse something special in the file 
    shipment = soup.find_all('span')
    Preparation=shipment[0] 
    Sent=shipment[1]
    InTransit=shipment[2]
    Delivered=shipment[3]

    print (url,';',"Preparation",Preparation.getText(),";","Sent",Sent.getText(),";","InTransit",InTransit.getText(),";","Delivered",Delivered.getText())
```

### Second question

```py
sys.stdout = open(file_path, "w")
print(url,';',"Preparation",Preparation.getText(),";","Sent",Sent.getText(),";","InTransit",InTransit.getText(),";","Delivered",Delivered.getText())`
```

Without keyword argument, print is writing to `sys.stdout`, which is by default your terminal output. There's only one print after `sys.sdtout = ...` so there will only be one line written to the file.

There's another way to print to a file :

```
with open('demo.txt', 'a') as f:
     print('Hello world', file = f)
```

The keyword `with` will ensure the file is closed even if an exception is raised.

### Both combined

From what I understood, you want to print two lines to the file. Here's a solution :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib

# read urls of websites from text file
list_open = open("c:/Users/***/Downloads/web list.txt")
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split("\n")
file_path = "randomfile.txt"

for url in line_in_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), "html")
    # parse something special in the file
    shipment = soup.find_all("span")
    Preparation = shipment[0]
    Sent = shipment[1]
    InTransit = shipment[2]
    Delivered = shipment[3]

    with open(file_path, "a") as f:
        f.write(
            f"{url} ; Preparation {Preparation.getText()}; Sent {Sent.getText()}; InTransit {InTransit.getText()}; Delivered {Delivered.getText()}"
        )
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed reply! I used the code of the solution but in the output file, I get only one result (the second URL result). Could you please suggest what can be the problem?

Comment: There was a typo (I copied the `with open...` line instead of editing as it should be. There was 2 file openings, the first was correct (parameter `"a"` for _appending_ to the file), the second was incorrect (parameter `"w"` for writing to a file).
It should be correct now !

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it, and it worked! Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_open = open("c:/Users/***/Downloads/web list.txt") 
read_list = list_open.read() 
line_in_list = read_list.split("\n") 

file_path = 'randomfile.txt'
sys.stdout = open(file_path, "w") 
There are four spans actuelly, try this
for url in line_in_list: 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read(), 'html') 
    # parse something special in the file 
    shipments = soup.find_all("span") # there are four span actually;
    sys.stdout.write('Url '+url+'; Preparation'+shipments[0].getText()+'; Sent'+shipments[1].getText()+'; InTransit'+shipments[2].getText()+'; Delivered'+shipments[3].getText()) 
    # change line
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I got the error: " sys.stdout = open(file_path, "w")
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined" Anything wrong here please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).